# Sharepoint 2010: Can't create a folder in a custom list

Tags: sharepoint, list, directory, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create folders in a set of custom lists I've created. However, when I try to do this, the New Folder button in the Ribbon is disabled. I read up on the matter; and this lead me to look to enable folder creation in List Settings -> Advance Settings. However, there doesn't seem to be an option to enable folder creation on the page. It shouldn't be a permission related issue; as I created the lists; and I'm also an admin on the farm.

I could use a document library; but we will not be uploading documents to the list; so this is more then I need.

What are my options, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. Turned out I was using a prerelease version of SP 2010; this was a bug.

Answer (score 12):

Go the the List Settings, go to Advanced List Settings and there should be an option there that reads: "Make "New Folder" command available?" Set that option to yes and you can create folders.

Good luck,
Patrick

Comment: +1 Although the accepted answer is a revelation to the OP, this answer is the solution to the Original Problem and I think should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Wiki Page Library instead? It's possible to add folders inside these.